Why does with_structured_output ignore optional params in Pydantic models
I am experimenting with Langchain's ability to take a Pydantic model and return a structured JSON-like output from an LLM. I guess I don't understand how Optional is being interpreted.
Example using the Pydantic model directly vs its JSON cousin in with_structured_output:
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

class Joke(BaseModel):
    """Joke to tell user."""

    setup: str = Field(description="The setup of the joke")
    punchline: str = Field(description="The punchline to the joke")
    rating: Optional[int] = Field(None, description="How funny the joke is, from 1 to 10")
    nonsense: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Placeholder, always return None")

class Joke2(BaseModel):
    """Joke to tell user."""

    setup: str = Field(description="The setup of the joke")
    punchline: str = Field(description="The punchline to the joke")
    rating: int = Field(description="How funny the joke is, from 1 to 10")
    nonsense: str = Field(description="Placeholder, always return None")

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo")

I'd expect Optional Fields to be returned always, since they are defined, even though a value may be None (the default value)
Below, I'd expect 1 and 2 to have the same output. Same with 3 and 4 (but different from 1 and 2). Only 2 and 4 behaved as I expected. Why did 1 and 3 not?
# 1) I'd expect `rating` to be returned since it's relevant enough to the prompt, and `nonsense` to be present with value of null
llm.with_structured_output(Joke).invoke("Tell me a joke about cats")
{'setup': 'Why was the cat sitting on the computer?',
 'punchline': 'To keep an eye on the mouse!'}

# 2) I'd expect `rating` to be returned since it's relevant enough to the prompt, and `nonsense` to be null
llm.with_structured_output(Joke.model_json_schema()).invoke("Tell me a joke about cats")
{'setup': 'Why was the cat sitting on the computer?',
 'punchline': 'To keep an eye on the mouse!',
 'rating': 8,
 'nonsense': None}

# 3) I'd expect `rating` to be returned and `nonsense` to be a string 'None'
llm.with_structured_output(Joke2).invoke("Tell me a joke about cats")
{'setup': 'Why was the cat sitting on the computer?',
 'punchline': 'To keep an eye on the mouse!',
 'rating': 5,
 'nonsense': 'This joke is purr-fectly hilarious!'}

# 4) I'd expect `rating` to be returned and `nonsense` to be a string 'None'
llm.with_structured_output(Joke2.model_json_schema()).invoke("Tell me a joke about cats")
{'setup': 'Why was the cat sitting on the computer?',
 'punchline': 'To keep an eye on the mouse!',
 'rating': 8,
 'nonsense': 'None'}


I'm guessing you will get better results if the prompt or field descriptions explains how to fill this field, and when is None a valid response in that field VS when it is required
